# Reactjs trying to useState but value won't change

Tags: reactjs, asp.net

I'm trying to update an id from two tables using a table component (using it twice to the same page). By clicking on a row I update the id of it to the parent component. I try to set it to a constant threw useState hook, but the constant does not change and it is permanently set to the initial state.

Here is the table component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useCallback, useState } from 'react';
import '@inovua/reactdatagrid-community/index.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import ReactDataGrid from '@inovua/reactdatagrid-community';
import './table.css';
const Table = (props) => {
    const [accountLicense, setAccountLicense] = useState([]);
    const [accountLicenseId, setAccountLicenseId] = useState("");
    useEffect(()=>{
        axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URI}/license/all/${accountLicenseId}`)
        .then(res=>{
            setAccountLicense(res.data);
        })
        .catch(e=>console.log(e));
    }, [])
    const onLicensesSelect = useCallback(({ data }) => {
        props.selectedAccount(data);
        props.accountLicenseId(data.id);
        setAccountLicenseId(data.id);
    }, [])
            return(
                <div>
                    <ReactDataGrid
                        idProperty='id'
                        columns={headers}
                        dataSource={accountLicense}
                        theme='default-light'
                        rtl={true}
                        enableSelection={true}
                    />
                    <div className='info'>{rowsText}</div>
                </div>
            )
}

export default Table
```

The response is:

```
AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 400',
name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
```

In the console window when I try to log the accountLicenseId it says it is "".

Comment: It seems like you're passing something wrong in the URL, I suggest you to test your API with Postman and if it's Postman response seems (Status code: 200) fine, than let me know - Will try to help you out in this code.

Comment: It's not, I tried to change the ${accountLicenseId} to 1 and the response was as expected.

Comment: So, the problem is useEffect is running on component render and at that time, accountLicenseId is null, which return 400. To confirm this, you can check in the network tab > Headers > Request URL and you will see the null there. please check it.

Comment: Yes you're right, the accountLicenseId constant is "", which makes the url not pass the id as expected.

Comment: If anyone run into my question I still couldn't get over it, maybe someone knows how to help me.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this isssue, You need to make two changes.

first set the accountLicenseId as null instead of "".

```
const [accountLicenseId, setAccountLicenseId] = useState(null);
```

Second things, you need to change the useEffect this way.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (accountLicenseId) {
    axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URI}/license/all/${accountLicenseId}`)
      .then(res => {
        setAccountLicense(res.data);
      })
      .catch(e => console.log(e));
  }
}, [accountLicenseId]);
```

Explanation: Only make the API request when accountLicenseId has a valid value and it's value changed.

Let me know, if you have any doubts :)

Comment: It's now just not making any request, instead of making it when the id updates.

Comment: Yeah, sending request with null values make no sense, that's why API call needs to be stop at that time. What are you expecting exactly ?

Comment: I update the id on a click in the useCallBack hook, but it won't update the id and the initial state remains.

Comment: Okay, please share a code on codesandbox if possible, So we can look into it.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/embed/goofy-voice-wrnj2v?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&view=editor

Comment: Hey, maybe you were able to watch it? I'm really stuck